# How to share scopes between classes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I have several Laravel models which have the same functionallity.

I'm trying to implement some sort of `::All()` functionallity but with another logic behind it.

For example: all my models have an "Active" boolean flag, which means that I get all of my languages like: `$language = Language::where('active', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();`. The same goes for hobbies, semesters, etc.

I'm trying to do something like this in my base_model from which all other models extend:

```
public static function getActive()
{
    return this::where('active', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();
}
```

this would save me lots and lots of redundant code, but as a newbie I'm struggling with the code.

How can I dynamically define the Model I want to retrieve?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Laravel [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) for this. For example:

```
//your base model
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    //every class inheriting from this will have this scope
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();
    }
}

//your child models will inherit the scope from the parent class
class Language extends BaseModel
{ 
    //your model's methods
}

//use the scope to get all the active languages
$languages = Language::active();
```

Comment: You are looking for Larevel Scopes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: I suggest using a repository pattern to filter eloquent models. https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/More/Repository